# Confused about custom types in SQL when sql.DB.Exec

Tags: mysql, sql, types, go, custom-type

Having this table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableName` (
    `Id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Status` enum('pending','rejected','sent','invalid') NOT NULL,
    `Body` varchar(255) NULL
) ENGINE='MyISAM' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
```

I have this (not complete) code **working fine**:

```
type StatusEnum string

const (
    STATUS_PENDING  StatusEnum = "pending"
    STATUS_REJECTED StatusEnum = "rejected"
    STATUS_SENT     StatusEnum = "sent"
    STATUS_INVALID  StatusEnum = "invalid"
)

func (s *StatusEnum) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    if src == nil {
        return errors.New("This field cannot be NULL")
    }

    if stringStatus, ok := src.([]byte); ok {
        *s = StatusEnum(string(stringStatus[:]))

        return nil
    }

    return errors.New("Cannot convert enum to string")
}

func (s *StatusEnum) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return []byte(*s), nil
}

type EmailQueue struct {
    Id        uint64
    Status    StatusEnum
    Body      sql.NullString
}

func Save (db *sql.DB) error {
    _, err = db.Exec(
        "UPDATE `tableName` SET `Status` = ?, `Body` = ? WHERE `id` = ?",
        &eqi.Status,
        eqi.Body,
        eqi.Id,
    )

    return err
}
```

So my question is: **Why do I need to use pointer reference (`&eqi.Status`) on `db.Exec`?**

Both `sql.NullString` and my custom `StatusEnum` are not implemented in `github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`, so why the difference?

If I don't use the pointer reference (`eqi.Status`), I'm getting this error (throwing in [database/sql/convert.go](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/convert.go#L37)):

```
sql: converting Exec argument #0's type: unsupported type emailqueue.StatusEnum, a string
```

I was trying to implement some other interfaces I've found with no luck.

I have other custom types implemented with `sql.Scanner` and `sql.driver.Valuer` interfaces, but the problem is the same.

I was guessing about `struct` and type inheritance differentiation, but I couldn't get any hint on that... :(

Please help to understand what's going on. Thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You implement the [Valuer interface](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer) for your `StatusEnum` type as operating on a `*StatusEnum`. Therefore when you pass one as a parameter to Exec it only makes sense as a pointer as only pointers to `StatusEnum` implement `Value()`, requiring a deference inline.

You don't have a definition for the `EmailList` type so I can suggest an alteration to your given `Valuer` interface.

```
func (s StatusEnum) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    return []byte(s), nil
}
```

This is the standard library [implements](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64) custom nullable types.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code replacing ```EmailList``` with ```StatusEnum```. This is more confusing though because this code just works perfectly: ```v, err := eqi.Status.Value()
 v, err = (&eqi.Status).Value()```

Comment: For anyone coming in and reading, this is because you can call a pointer method on a non pointer value and it will automatically take the address, but only if it is a non interface method, i.e. the variable is an interface. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values